# Do webpages have unique identifiers (other than URL)?

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing JavaScript to attach to a site where we cannot edit the HTML. It should run only on certain pages, hiding some text boxes if this customer wants that done.

The example I was given uses `document.title` to distinguish one page from another. The problem is that some pages have duplicate titles as they come from the product name (i.e. "Notecards"). The URLs are long, complex strings that are generated based on the user, and thus I cannot use them as it must apply to all users.

Is there any other attribute that a page will already have that I can use either in place of the title or in addition to it?

Comment: nope. an html file is pretty agnostic to where its located.

Comment: "It should run only on certain pages"  Presumably those pages have unique URLs?  So why do you need anything else?  Possibly you can inspect the DOM of each page for certain characteristics, but checking the URL seems simplest.

Comment: The URL changes based on the logged on user and I need this to run for every user. It's a long, random string.

Comment: _"The URL changes based on the logged on user"_ Surely the user portion of the URL is appended to some unique URL base?

Comment: The "long random string" is likely part of the query parameters. If you want just the location of the document you could use `window.location.pathname`

Comment: The base is "uStore/OrderFinalStep.aspx?qs=" and that is identical for all products. This webpage was not built to be friendly to updates.

Comment: How does the server know what product to render if the URL is identical for all products?

Comment: 'window.location.pathname' returns only the "OrderFinalStep" element, which is identical for all products.

Comment: The random string is not identical, but in changes based on logged in user. I can access the logged in user information from the server, but they do not let us get product information from the server because we're not paying the $$$$ for the next tier.

Comment: _"because we're not paying the $$$$ for the next tier"_ I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: I was just hoping there was something else out there, as there's no way we'll get that upgrade.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my suggestion of inspecting the DOM for specific characteristics, possibly product-specific, such as a sku or product identifier that might be likely to appear in the same part of the page?

Comment: This really reads like a big [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  It's not exactly clear what you are really trying to accomplish, but you are definitely asking about a possible solution, and it's not really clear how this information helps you.  Perhaps you might consider re-wording the question a bit and describing a bit more about what it is you are actually trying to accomplish, even if it means you have to mention the name of some third party framework in the process.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty I missed that part of your first comment. I did find a productID buried in the page. Hopefully that should work for me.

Comment: Web servers can return an [ETag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) in an HTTP response header to uniquely identify a version of a page.